# Sublime Text builds that use pdfLatex fail

Tags: sublime-text, latextools

I'm attempting to use one of a few ST resources to build latex documents, but none of them are working. The initial attempt was to use pandoc from ST to do markdown/latex compilation. I was using this build script:

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "pandoc -o \"$file.pdf\" \"$file\" && open -a Preview \"$file.pdf\"",
    "selector": "text.html.markdown",
    "path": "/usr/texbin:$PATH"
}
```

which brings up the console box, says it is building, but doesn't create a pdf in my directory.

SOLUTION:

```
{
    "cmd": ["pandoc -o \"$file.pdf\" \"$file\" && open -a Preview \"$file.pdf\""],
    "shell": "true",
    "selector": "text.html.markdown",
    "path": "/usr/texbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"
}
```

I should mention that

```
> pandoc -o example.pdf example.md
```

works from the command line.

Next I tried just using latexTools and the usual latex build system. I created a latex file in ST, and tried to build. I got the exact same behavior, blank console box, no output into the directory.

So I thought maybe my pdfLatex was the issue:

```
> which pdflatex
/usr/texbin/pdflatex
```

and

```
> pdflatex --version
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014)
kpathsea version 6.2.0
Copyright 2014 Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
Compiled with libpng 1.6.10; using libpng 1.6.10
Compiled with zlib 1.2.8; using zlib 1.2.8
Compiled with xpdf version 3.03
```

and then I tried:

```
> pdflatex example.tex
```

which also worked(output the pdf file as expected).

Edit: I am getting some output in the console:

```
    Writing file /Users/bbischof/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User/Markdown to PDF.sublime-build with encoding UTF-8
Writing file /Users/bbischof/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User/Markdown to PDF.sublime-build with encoding UTF-8
Running 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./sublime_plugin.py", line 337, in run_
  File "./exec.py", line 154, in run
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'shell_cmd'
```

Edit 2: Removed `"shell_cmd"` and made it `"cmd"`. If I run it like this with simply `"cmd"` I get:

```
    [Errno 2] No such file or directory
[cmd:  [u'pandoc -o "/Users/bbischof/Documents/LatexDocs/example.md.pdf" "/Users/bbischof/Documents/LatexDocs/example.md" && open -a Preview "/Users/bbischof/Documents/LatexDocs/example.md.pdf"']]
[dir:  /Users/bbischof/Documents/LatexDocs]
[path: /usr/texbin:/usr/texbin:/usr/texbin:/usr/texbin:/usr/texbin:/usr/texbin:/usr/texbin:/usr/texbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
[Finished]
```

If I run it with cmd and `"shell": "true",` I get:

```
/bin/sh: pandoc: command not found
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 127]
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, but I have tried restarting ST since installing these things and saving the build-scripts.

Comment: Does anything appear in the Sublime console? (**View|Console**)

Comment: @ig0774 no, it's blank.

Comment: LaTeXTools is pretty chatty on the console and may provide a clue... Maybe running `pandoc` with `--verbose`?

Comment: @ig0774 sorry, do you mean running pandoc in the ST console? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Just setting the verbose flag in the builder command

Comment: @ig0774 oh, duh. Sorry. I added verbose and still nothing in the consol window, and still no output pdf.

Comment: @ig0774 Sorry I was wrong, there is output, edited the question to include.

Comment: Oh... I think you just can't use `shell_cmd` on ST2. Could you try using `cmd` instead of `shell_cmd` and set the `shell` option to `true`?

Comment: @ig0774 getting closer... changed the cmd_shell to cmd, and added shell true, that gives me errors(added in edit). Remove shell true and differnt errors(added in edit)

Comment: So what's the output of `which pandoc` (from a terminal window)? Most likely it's a directory not on the default `$PATH` for GUI programs... E.g. `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: /usr/local/bin/pandoc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36242/discussion-between-bbischof-and-ig0774).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So lay out what's in the chat, the path to the pandoc executable, i.e., `/usr/local/bin` must be added to the `path` setting of your builder as well as `/usr/texbin` (to ensure pdflatex and friends can be found).

So your `path` setting should be:

`"path": "/usr/texbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH"`